# Helm swoop: How to invert match

Tags: helm

How can I invert a helm-swoop match, i.e. how can I show all lines *not* matching the pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you begin the pattern with an exclamation point, it will match lines that do not match the pattern.

So `!window` will match all lines that do not have `window` on them.

This is a [helm feature](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Buffers#buffers-by-major-mode), so you can use it in other places than just helm swoop.

Also note that it doesn't negate the entire search, just the token beginning with `!`, so you can search for, e.g., `defun !--`, and it will show you all lines with function definitions (`defun`), for public functions (i.e., they do not have `--` in the name).